# Java program does not execute in Android

Tags: android

I am doing a weather project in android. The information is from a given URL which is static and contains a list of cities. For example: `HTTP://myexample/info/?cities` displays a list of cities. `HTTP://myexample/info/?tokyo`  will display: Tokyo, Japan.

I have done the layout to write down the name of the city to be executed:

```
xmlns:tools=["http://schemas.android.com/tools"]
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Meteo" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="3">              

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/soleil" />
    </LinearLayout> 
            <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >
            <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But the Java program doesn't execute. Only the layout is executed:

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // URL
    String url = "$HTTP://myexample/info/?cities$";

    // Weather information

    String weather = "Tokyo, Japan#15.5#Sun ##";

    // Get the city name
    String city = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1).trim();

    System.out.println(city);
    // Check the weather of the city: 15.5#Sun
    // Remove city name
    // Remove last #

    if (weather.toLowerCase().contains(city.toLowerCase())) {

        // Get condition: 

        String condition = weather.substring(weather.indexOf("#") + 1,
                weather.length() - 2);
        System.out.println(condition);
        // Split with # sign and you have a list of conditions

        String[] information = condition.split("#");
        for (int i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(information[i]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "java program don't execute, just the layout is executed"?

Comment: There is a `main` method in Android ([here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java#4720)) but that's used by the system already to start your app. The official [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) is quite nice

Comment: @zapl Aha! I always assumed that, but did not know for sure. Thanks for the ActivityThread code. :)

Comment: @Tudor have errors i can't run the program

Comment: This should not be tagged with java-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up [Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). In Android you'll have to create a class that extends Activity. The equivalent to the `main()` method is the `OnCreate()` method. In this method you can set your layout with `setContentView(layout id)`

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse `main()` method is not supported in android.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      // .... 

}
```

Use `Activity` instead.

```
public class MyActivity extendsActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstance)
    {
       // This method will be called first
       super.onCreate(saveInstance);
       // Your definition
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problems is that you are trying to run an **Android** application as a **Java** application.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Is the standard entry point for a **Java** application.

In **Android**, things are a little different.

First, class **Demo** must extend **Activity**:

```
public class Demo extends Activity
```

Second, you have to implement special methods, which are invoked at specific moments of the life time of your application, the most important being:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { }

protected void onPause()  { }

protected void onResume() { }
```

You should check the corresponding documentation at [Android Developers Site](http://developer.android.com/index.html).